# NEO4J query with MATCH, WHERE, doesn't work

Tags: neo4j, where-clause, sql-like

I want to do a request, it doesn't work:

here is the code (in NEO4J sandbox, the csv file is in google sheets, publicly accessible):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17UhQ3m2dE3wS4IsBjgv0ozcW_zH2rSBs2ZUdqeT4cQw/export?format=csv&id=17UhQ3m2dE3wS4IsBjgv0ozcW_zH2rSBs2ZUdqeT4cQw&gid=726094387' AS line

MERGE (cp:cp {Name:line.cp})
MERGE (commune:commune {Name:line.commune})
MERGE (voie:voie {Name:line.rao_libelle_voie})
MERGE (adr:adr {Name:line.adr_lib_ap_ocr_postal_0})
MERGE (name:name {Name:line.adr_l1_name})

MERGE (cp) -[:TO {dist:line.count} ]-> (commune)
MERGE (commune) -[:TO {dist:line.count} ]-> (voie)
MERGE (voie) -[:TO {dist:line.count} ]-> (adr)
MERGE (adr) -[:TO {dist:line.count} ]-> (name)
```

Here my request ( I want the name of the inhabitants (adr_l1_name, variable :name) of a street in (rao_libelle_voie, variable: voie );

Here is the SQL request (from an other source):

```
SELECT `adr_l1_name` 
  FROM `database`
  WHERE ` rao_libelle_voie ` LIKE '%RUE DE GLAIRE%'
```

The result is working;

In NEO4J sandbox, i make this request:

```
MATCH (n:name)
WHERE (n:voie) = 'RUE DE GLAIRE'
RETURN (n:name)
```

There is no error message, but no results appear;

Answer (score 0):

Updated with what the op the actually wanted

```
// match all of the name on a particular voie
MATCH (v:voie)--(:adr)--(n:name)
WHERE (v.Name) = 'RUE DE GLAIRE'

// return voie and the collection of names
RETURN v, collect(n) as names
```

**Old Answer**

It is just a mismatch between how you loaded your data and then how you are asking for it afterwards. Labels and Attributes are case sensitive in Neo4j.

You loaded all of your data with lower case labels (cp, commune, voi, addr, name) and you made the identifying attribute propercase `Name`.

And in your query you actually look for the label `:name` rather than `:voie`

If you change your query to look like this...

```
// match "voie" nodes identified by "n"
MATCH (n:voie)

// where the "Name" is "RUE DE GLAIRE" 
WHERE (n.Name) = 'RUE DE GLAIRE'

// return just the name
RETURN n.Name
```

To make it more equivalent to your SQL query you could write it like this...

```
MATCH (n:voie)
WHERE (n.Name) CONTAINS 'RUE DE GLAIRE'
RETURN n.Name
```

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, I tried the query above, and I had this response:

`n.Name
"RUE DE GLAIRE"`

But I wanted the name of the inhabitants of this street (for example, in 'RUE DE GLAIRE', Mr Dupond, Ms Martin, etc.);

Comment: ahh, sorry, i wasn't really understanding. I think I updated the answer with what you actually wanted.